# How can I call method in activity class from non-activity class(Junit of uiautomator class)

Tags: android

I have an activity class like below

```
public class PInfo extends Activity {

    public ArrayList<String> getInstalledApps() {

        ArrayList<String> Apps = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and non-activity class like below

```
public class TestSettings extends UiAutomatorTestCase {

    public void testSearch() throws UiObjectNotFoundException, IOException {

        try {
            PInfo pi = new PInfo();
            ArrayList<String> marr = pi.getInstalledApps();
```

---

When calling `getInstalledApps()` method, It's not working normally.

Is there any solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956018/can-i-create-the-object-of-a-activity-in-other-class. check this. do not create an instance of activity class

Comment: Check the answer [here][1]

create a callback interface


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662851/how-to-call-method-in-activity-form-non-activity-class

Answer (score 1):

you can make this method to be static like this --> public static .... getInstalledApps()