# Cannot call method from another activity

Tags: java, android, methods

I cannot call method from another activity in **OnNotificationPosted**. I also tried to make instance of activity but failed. I searched alot but no success. please help

**NotificationListener**

```
public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        otherActivity oth = new otherActivity();
        oth.loc();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.i("Msg", "Notification Removed");
    }
}
```

**otherActivity**

```
public class OtherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_other);

    }

    public void loc() {
//code body
    }
}
```

Comment: try this `((OtherActivity)this).loc();`

Comment: then what to do? I only want to call method from that activity

Comment: it is not working bro

Comment: what error you get.

Comment: you can not instantiate the activity with new keywork. If you want call loc() method, make it **public static** and call **OtherActivity.loc()**

Comment: you getting issue because you calling activity method in not-activity class.that's why you have to implement callback interface. have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19663089/5110595) hope it will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class OtherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_other);

        }

          public static void loc(){
                //code body 
            }

    }
```

how to using :     otherActivity.loc();

```
public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
   otherActivity.loc();

}
@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    Log.i("Msg","Notification Removed");
}
```

Comment: I cannot make it static because the implementation of method goes wrong